# Java desktop app: How to maximize tray application when hotkey pressed?

Tags: java, desktop, hotkeys, system-tray

I need to write a program that, when minimized, lives in the System Tray, and I'll use Java 6's SystemTray API to do that.

**How can I make that application comes to the foreground when the user presses some hotkey?**

For example, the app is running but minimized.  When the user presses CTRL-SHIFT-Y or something (or, like Google Desktop's search, CTRL twice) and the application is maximized.

EDIT: I know about [how to bring a Java window to the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309023/howto-bring-a-java-window-to-the-front).  I'm asking more specifically about ***how to make a running Java app listen for a hotkey***.

Comment: I searched for hours for a solution to this problem. 
Found nothing which doesn't involve JNI.
It is very sad that Sun (or now, Oracle) don't care about Java on the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to resort to JNI, check out [an example](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=147913).

Here's [another nice example](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=632369) from Sun's forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SWT extension library to create a keyboard hook that can listen for your hot key - http://feeling.sourceforge.net/

note, that this is windows only (but that may not be a problem for you).