# How to bring JDialog to the top

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Howto bring a Java window to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309023/howto-bring-a-java-window-to-the-front)

I have created a java application. Now I write that if the JDialog is not present then It will create another JDialog but If its present then i set it as setVisible as true. But the problem is that if JDialog is there and after that i opened other applications like internet explorer then my application is not shown on top. So i made setAlwaysOnTop as true so the main problem i faced is that if after my application if i open other applications then those applications always displayed in the backside of my application which is wrong also. I want if there is JDialog already present then bring to the top but not for always.

Comment: This might be your solution: [howto-bring-a-java-window-to-the-front](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309023/howto-bring-a-java-window-to-the-front)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage your windows according to external windows, sadly you'll have to resort to native calls (JNI, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Assign that JDialog to an object and dispose that JDialog then assign the object to the JDialog