# How to set default download location property for chrome using selenium wedriver in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I want to set automatic download in specified download location using webdriver. I tried following code which is not working for chrome:

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("download.default_directory", downloadPath);
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Can you please correct me where i am wrong?

Comment: Maybe this answer, don't know if it's working though : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9900378/3805954

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more current answer for people like me who are searching for this and kept coming back to a question asked 3 years ago. This was answered by Chromium support [here in Comment 8:](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=606)  in April '15.

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\New_Download");

DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

I have tested it locally and it works. You may need to add the following option argument to disable extensions like I did, which is, options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you'll be able to perform download setting only chromeOption due to the following reason:

[ChromeOptions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html) class does contain implementation of download path argument.

But I would recommend you to use alternative approach, although it looks more complicated:

```
package com.lazerycode.selenium.filedownloader;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Set;

public class FileDownloader {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FileDownloader.class);
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String localDownloadPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    private boolean followRedirects = true;
    private boolean mimicWebDriverCookieState = true;
    private int httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt = 0;

    public FileDownloader(WebDriver driverObject) {
        this.driver = driverObject;
    }

    /**
     * Specify if the FileDownloader class should follow redirects when trying to download a file
     *
     * @param value
     */
    public void followRedirectsWhenDownloading(boolean value) {
        this.followRedirects = value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current location that files will be downloaded to.
     *
     * @return The filepath that the file will be downloaded to.
     */
    public String localDownloadPath() {
        return this.localDownloadPath;
    }

    /**
     * Set the path that files will be downloaded to.
     *
     * @param filePath The filepath that the file will be downloaded to.
     */
    public void localDownloadPath(String filePath) {
        this.localDownloadPath = filePath;
    }

    /**
     * Download the file specified in the href attribute of a WebElement
     *
     * @param element
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public String downloadFile(WebElement element) throws Exception {
        return downloader(element, "href");
    }

    /**
     * Download the image specified in the src attribute of a WebElement
     *
     * @param element
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public String downloadImage(WebElement element) throws Exception {
        return downloader(element, "src");
    }

    /**
     * Gets the HTTP status code of the last download file attempt
     *
     * @return
     */
    public int getHTTPStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt() {
        return this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt;
    }

    /**
     * Mimic the cookie state of WebDriver (Defaults to true)
     * This will enable you to access files that are only available when logged in.
     * If set to false the connection will be made as an anonymouse user
     *
     * @param value
     */
    public void mimicWebDriverCookieState(boolean value) {
        this.mimicWebDriverCookieState = value;
    }

    /**
     * Load in all the cookies WebDriver currently knows about so that we can mimic the browser cookie state
     *
     * @param seleniumCookieSet
     * @return
     */
    private BasicCookieStore mimicCookieState(Set seleniumCookieSet) {
        BasicCookieStore mimicWebDriverCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        for (Cookie seleniumCookie : seleniumCookieSet) {
            BasicClientCookie duplicateCookie = new BasicClientCookie(seleniumCookie.getName(), seleniumCookie.getValue());
            duplicateCookie.setDomain(seleniumCookie.getDomain());
            duplicateCookie.setSecure(seleniumCookie.isSecure());
            duplicateCookie.setExpiryDate(seleniumCookie.getExpiry());
            duplicateCookie.setPath(seleniumCookie.getPath());
            mimicWebDriverCookieStore.addCookie(duplicateCookie);
        }

        return mimicWebDriverCookieStore;
    }

    /**
     * Perform the file/image download.
     *
     * @param element
     * @param attribute
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws NullPointerException
     */
    private String downloader(WebElement element, String attribute) throws IOException, NullPointerException, URISyntaxException {
        String fileToDownloadLocation = element.getAttribute(attribute);
        if (fileToDownloadLocation.trim().equals("")) throw new NullPointerException("The element you have specified does not link to anything!");

        URL fileToDownload = new URL(fileToDownloadLocation);
        File downloadedFile = new File(this.localDownloadPath + fileToDownload.getFile().replaceFirst("/|\\\\", ""));
        if (downloadedFile.canWrite() == false) downloadedFile.setWritable(true);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        LOG.info("Mimic WebDriver cookie state: " + this.mimicWebDriverCookieState);
        if (this.mimicWebDriverCookieState) {
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, mimicCookieState(this.driver.manage().getCookies()));
        }

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(fileToDownload.toURI());
        HttpParams httpRequestParameters = httpget.getParams();
        httpRequestParameters.setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, this.followRedirects);
        httpget.setParams(httpRequestParameters);

        LOG.info("Sending GET request for: " + httpget.getURI());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget, localContext);
        this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        LOG.info("HTTP GET request status: " + this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt);
        LOG.info("Downloading file: " + downloadedFile.getName());
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(response.getEntity().getContent(), downloadedFile);
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();

        String downloadedFileAbsolutePath = downloadedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        LOG.info("File downloaded to '" + downloadedFileAbsolutePath + "'");

        return downloadedFileAbsolutePath;
    }

}
```

appropriate examples of the code above usage:

```
@Test
public void downloadAFile() throws Exception {
    FileDownloader downloadTestFile = new FileDownloader(driver);
    driver.get("http://www.localhost.com/downloadTest.html");
    WebElement downloadLink = driver.findElement(By.id("fileToDownload"));
    String downloadedFileAbsoluteLocation = downloadTestFile.downloadFile(downloadLink);

    assertThat(new File(downloadedFileAbsoluteLocation).exists(), is(equalTo(true)));
    assertThat(downloadTestFile.getHTTPStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt(), is(equalTo(200)));
}

@Test
public void downloadAnImage() throws Exception {
    FileDownloader downloadTestFile = new FileDownloader(driver);
    driver.get("http://www.localhost.com//downloadTest.html");
    WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.id("ebselenImage"));
    String downloadedImageAbsoluteLocation = downloadTestFile.downloadImage(image);

    assertThat(new File(downloadedImageAbsoluteLocation).exists(), is(equalTo(true)));
    assertThat(downloadTestFile.getHTTPStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt(), is(equalTo(200)));
}
```

This one example is taken from  [How To Download Files With Selenium And Why You Shouldn’t](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/)  . Look through it to get more details. Hope it helps you.

Comment: A very nice solution, but it will not work the file download is pasword protected and authorization is not solved by cookies.