# How to set the size of the selenium window? (in python, on Mac, using chromedriver)

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So this is just weird. I can't seem to do a very simple task with selenum; change the size of the window. As the title states, im using Python on a Mac and specifically using chromedriver.

I have tried this:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=200,200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=EXE_PATH, chrome_options=options)
```

I've tried changing "window-size" to "--window-size" and removed the headless option. I've also tried using set_window_size after opening the page I want. None of it works. set_window_size actually gives an error and the above use of the Options class doesnt crash but the window stays the same size it always is.

I found this thread from 2012:

[Mac selenium webdriver chrome window always starts with a small window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607753/mac-selenium-webdriver-chrome-window-always-starts-with-a-small-window)

But can't believe a library as popular as selenium still doesn't offer a way to resize windows easily, and can't find any other suggestions beyond those tweaks I already said I tried. Thanks.

Comment: It is very simple, karimkohel answer perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

i guess you can try

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome()
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
```