# How to run an application(process) in java as background

Tags: java

How to run an application(process) in java as background process.It should run back to my application my application shopuld be always on foreground.I am using

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "C:/Program Files/Vehicle Spy 3/vspy3Demo.exe");
```

I have also used "/c" like the following:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "C:/Program Files/Vehicle Spy 3/vspy3Demo.exe /c");
```

But it is every time opening in foreground any one can help me..

Comment: java only starts the external application. It has no control whatsoever on what the app does later on..

Comment: If you are running a Swing Application then you might try [Window#setAlwaysOnTop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)). That way your application might cover other application you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the widget toolkit you're using (swing, swt etc), I would suggest setting a timeout (e.g. 1 second) and then bring your java app window on top again.

Example with swt

```
shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    shell.forceActive(); // assuming shell is your java app main window
}
```

[Example with Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309023/how-to-bring-a-window-to-the-front):

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myFrame.toFront(); // assuming myFrame is your java app main window
        myFrame.repaint();
    }
});
```