# How to minimize an external non-java application on a condition and display JFrame to front?

Tags: java

I am developing a timer (somewhat like a cafe manager for a small business) which displays the login frame upon time-out. I have used the `Robot` class and it works perfectly except when I am playing League of Legends (which is in full screen mode).

How do I minimize it/bring my JFrame to front?

I tried using `toFront()` and `repaint()` methods but they did not work. The frame would just display behind the game window.

Comment: actually does not seem a problem... Will cofee staff play LOL at working time??

Comment: I am doing this program for personal use. We have pcs being rented by LoL players.

Comment: Ohhh... I understand!!! Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309023/how-to-bring-a-window-to-the-front

Comment: I've checked this but the problem seems to be still there. I am searching for more answers and also try the other answers there with a little different implementation. Thank you for you suggestion anyway.

Comment: Full screen mode forces something to go at the front. It's impossible to byass this.

Comment: Is that so. Thanks then